# Exporting .jpg files from data driven pages in Arcmap (name file is a text)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages, python-script-tool

I am trying to export my Data Driven Pages to JPEG files named wiht an index layer field. I have used the code posted in other answer and it seems to work fine when the page names are numbers. However, what I have found is that I can not use it when my page name is a string (may contains alphabetical characters), i.e. it works fine with page numbers: 1, 2, 3... but does not work with page names 'page1', 'page2', 'page3'.

```
import arcpy, string

#Read input parameters from script tool
mxdPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
pageList = string.split(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3), ";")

#Reference the map and the data driven page object
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
for eachPage in pageList:
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(eachPage))
    pageID = str(ddp.getPageIDFromName(str(eachPage.strip("'"))))
    ddp.currentPageID = int(pageID)
    arcpy.AddMessage(pageID)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd,str(eachPage)+ ".jpg")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If "does not work" means you see an error message can you include it in your question, please?

Comment: It means that it does not zoom to right entity. Instead, the files are called with the correct names but they show the same image all the time.

Comment: When you pass 'page1', does it not give you an error when you try to cast that as an int on the line with int(pageID)?

Comment: Are the DDP referencing features on an attrubute that has values of "page1" etc?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I think you should also include `print` statements for your `mxdPath` and `pageList` immediately after they are set from a tool dialog which we cannot see.  That way we can see what gets passed into later code.  For help with Python code we need to see the exact snippet that you are running, any output from print statements, and any errors when that code snippet is run.

Comment: After many hours of works, I realize that the script works fine with string name and integer names. The only thing you have to do is to  save your .mxd after change de DDP to use the script . The problem was that it exported last view you have saved and not the current view of your DDP. Thanks a lot for your help and please taking account that the code is correct.